# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open &#39; Cannot upload a file to remote server using multer in express js app

Tags: express, ssh, multer

Here is my api

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const multer  = require('multer')

//Configuration for Multer
const upload = multer({ dest: "../public/data/uploads" });

router.post("/uploadFile", upload.single("myFile"), (req, res) => {
  // Stuff to be added later
  console.log(req.file);
  res.send("jodwajo" + req.file)
});
```

and yes the destination "../public/data/uploads" exists

[image: but when I hit the route through Postman I get the below error]
The api works when i run it on my local computer i.e localhost but not when i try it on live server